# PorterDuffXfermode error when using with ViewPager2

Tags: android, kotlin

I created a custom view for onboarding customers to our app the view works fine when using Fragment and activity items but when using the same with ViewPager2 item it's not working properly. I have tried using different **PorterDuffXfermode** but it doesn't work.

I am adding two screenshots one is when using with Fragments other is when using Viewpager2

[image: When Using With Fragment] [image: When Using with ViewPager2]

```
class GuideView private constructor(context: Context, view: View?, type: TargetType?, tourStep: Int, iOnTourButton: IOnTourButtonClicked?) : FrameLayout(context) {
    private val selfPaint = Paint()
    private val paintLine = Paint()
    private val paintCircle = Paint()
    private val paintCircle2 = Paint()
    private val paintCircleInner = Paint()
    private val targetPaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    private val X_FER_MODE_CLEAR: Xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
    private val target: View?
    var tourStep: Int = 0

    private var targetRect: RectF? = null
    private val selfRect = Rect()
    private val density: Float
    private var stopY = 0f
    private var isTop = false
    var isShowing = false
        private set
    private var yMessageView = 0
    private var startYLineAndCircle = 0f
    private var circleIndicatorSize = 0f
    private var circleIndicatorSizeFinal = 0f
    private var circleInnerIndicatorSize = 0f
    private var lineIndicatorWidthSize = 0f
    private var messageViewPadding = 0
    private var marginGuide = 0f
    private var strokeCircleWidth = 0f
    private var indicatorHeight = 0f
    private var mGuideListener: GuideListener? = null
    private var iOnTourButton: IOnTourButtonClicked? = null
    private var skipPresse: SkipPressed? = null
    private var mGravity: GRAVITY? = null
    private var mTargetType: TargetType? = null
    private var dismissType: DismissType? = null
    private val mMessageView: GuideMessageView
    private var isNeeded: Boolean? = true

    private fun init() {
        lineIndicatorWidthSize = LINE_INDICATOR_WIDTH_SIZE * density
        marginGuide = MARGIN_INDICATOR * density
        indicatorHeight = INDICATOR_HEIGHT * density
        messageViewPadding = (MESSAGE_VIEW_PADDING * density).toInt()
        strokeCircleWidth = STROKE_CIRCLE_INDICATOR_SIZE * density
        circleIndicatorSizeFinal = CIRCLE_INDICATOR_SIZE * density
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        if (target != null) {
            selfPaint.color = BACKGROUND_COLOR
            selfPaint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
            selfPaint.isAntiAlias = true
            canvas.drawRect(selfRect, selfPaint)
            paintLine.style = Paint.Style.FILL
            paintLine.color = LINE_INDICATOR_COLOR
            paintLine.strokeWidth = lineIndicatorWidthSize
            paintLine.isAntiAlias = true
            paintCircle.style = Paint.Style.FILL
            paintCircle2.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            paintCircle.color = CIRCLE_INDICATOR_COLOR
            paintCircle2.color = Color.parseColor("#236EA5")
            paintCircle.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
            paintCircle2.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
            paintCircle.strokeWidth = strokeCircleWidth
            paintCircle2.strokeWidth = strokeCircleWidth
            paintCircle.isAntiAlias = true
            paintCircle2.isAntiAlias = true
            paintCircleInner.style = Paint.Style.FILL
            paintCircleInner.color = CIRCLE_INNER_INDICATOR_COLOR
            paintCircleInner.isAntiAlias = true
            val x = (target.left / 2 + target.right / 2).toFloat()
            val location = IntArray(2)
            target.getLocationOnScreen(location)
            val location1 = IntArray(2)
            val view: View
            var circleposX = location[0] + target.width.toFloat()
            var circleposY = location[1].toFloat() + target.height / 2
            var x2 = selfRect.right.toFloat()
            var x3 = selfRect.left.toFloat()
            var y2 = selfRect.bottom.toFloat()
            targetPaint.xfermode = X_FER_MODE_CLEAR
            targetPaint.isAntiAlias = true
            if (target is Targetable) {
                (target as Targetable).guidePath()?.let { canvas.drawPath(it, targetPaint) }
            } else {
                if (mTargetType == TargetType.CIRCLE) {
                    canvas.drawCircle(targetRect!!.centerX(), targetRect!!.centerY(), target.width / 2.toFloat(), targetPaint)
                    canvas.drawCircle(targetRect!!.centerX(), targetRect!!.centerY(), target.width / 2 + 5.toFloat(), paintCircle2)
                } else
                    canvas.drawRoundRect(targetRect!!, RADIUS_SIZE_TARGET_RECT.toFloat(), RADIUS_SIZE_TARGET_RECT.toFloat(), targetPaint)
            }

            when (tourStep) {
                1 -> {
                    view = mMessageView.getTitleTextView()
                    view.getLocationOnScreen(location1)
                    val x1 = location1[0].toFloat()
                    val y1 = location1[1] + view.height.toFloat()
                    circleposX = location[0].toFloat()
                    circleposY = location[1].toFloat() + target.height / 2
                    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, circleposY, paintLine)
                    canvas.drawLine(x1, circleposY, circleposX - circleIndicatorSize - 10, circleposY, paintLine)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleIndicatorSize, paintCircle)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleInnerIndicatorSize, paintCircleInner)
                }
                2 -> {
                    view = mMessageView.getTitleTextView()
                    view.getLocationOnScreen(location1)
                    val x1 = location1[0].toFloat()
                    val y1 = location1[1] + view.height / 2.toFloat()
                    circleposX = location[0] - 30.toFloat()
                    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, circleposX, y1, paintLine)
                    canvas.drawLine(circleposX, y1, circleposX, circleposY - circleIndicatorSize - 10, paintLine)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleIndicatorSize, paintCircle)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleInnerIndicatorSize, paintCircleInner)
                }
                3 -> {
                    view = mMessageView.getTitleTextView()
                    view.getLocationOnScreen(location1)
                    val x1 = location1[0].toFloat()
                    val y1 = location1[1] + view.height.toFloat()
                    circleposX = location[0].toFloat()
                    circleposY = location[1].toFloat() + target.height / 2
                    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, circleposY, paintLine)
                    canvas.drawLine(x1, circleposY, circleposX - circleIndicatorSize - 10, circleposY, paintLine)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleIndicatorSize, paintCircle)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleInnerIndicatorSize, paintCircleInner)
                }
                4 -> {
                    view = mMessageView.getTitleTextView()
                    view.getLocationOnScreen(location1)
                    val x1 = location1[0].toFloat()
                    val y1 = location1[1] + view.height / 2.toFloat()
                    circleposX = location[0] - 30.toFloat()
                    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, circleposY, paintLine)
                    canvas.drawLine(x1, circleposY, circleposX - circleIndicatorSize - 10, circleposY, paintLine)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleIndicatorSize, paintCircle)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleInnerIndicatorSize, paintCircleInner)
                }
                5 -> {
                    view = mMessageView.getTitleTextView()
                    view.getLocationOnScreen(location1)
                    val x1 = location1[0].toFloat()
                    val y1 = location1[1] + view.height / 2.toFloat()
                    circleposX = location[0] - 30.toFloat()
                    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, circleposY, paintLine)
                    canvas.drawLine(x1, circleposY, circleposX - circleIndicatorSize - 10, circleposY, paintLine)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleIndicatorSize, paintCircle)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleInnerIndicatorSize, paintCircleInner)
                }
                6 -> {
                    view = mMessageView.getContextTextView()
                    view.getLocationOnScreen(location1)
                    val x1 = location1[0].toFloat()
                    val y1 = location1[1] + view.height.toFloat()
                    circleposX = x3 + location[0] + 100*density
                    circleposY = location[1] + 100*density
                    /*canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, circleposX, y1, paintLine)*/
                    canvas.drawLine(circleposX, y1, circleposX, circleposY - circleIndicatorSize - 10, paintLine)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleIndicatorSize, paintCircle)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleInnerIndicatorSize, paintCircleInner)
                }
                7 -> {
                    view = mMessageView.getTitleTextView()
                    view.getLocationOnScreen(location1)
                    val x1 = location1[0] + (view.width.toFloat() / 2)
                    val y1 = location1[1].toFloat()
                    circleposX = location[0] + target.width / 2.toFloat()
                    circleposY = location[1] + target.height.toFloat()
                    canvas.drawLine(circleposX, y1, circleposX, circleposY + circleIndicatorSize + 10, paintLine)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleIndicatorSize, paintCircle)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleInnerIndicatorSize, paintCircleInner)
                }
                8 -> {
                    view = mMessageView.getContextTextView()
                    view.getLocationOnScreen(location1)
                    val x1 = location1[0].toFloat()
                    val y1 = location1[1] + view.height / 2.toFloat()
                    circleposX = x1 - 20.toFloat()
                    circleposY = location[1].toFloat()
                    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, circleposX, y1, paintLine)
                    canvas.drawLine(circleposX, y1, circleposX, circleposY - circleIndicatorSize - 10, paintLine)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleIndicatorSize, paintCircle)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleInnerIndicatorSize, paintCircleInner)
                }
                9 -> {
                    view = mMessageView.getContextTextView()
                    view.getLocationOnScreen(location1)
                    val y1 = location1[1] + view.height.toFloat()
                    circleposX = location[0] + target.width.toFloat()
                    canvas.drawLine(circleposX, y1, circleposX, circleposY - circleIndicatorSize - 10, paintLine)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleIndicatorSize, paintCircle)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleInnerIndicatorSize, paintCircleInner)
                }
                10 -> {
                    view = mMessageView.getContextTextView()
                    view.getLocationOnScreen(location1)
                    val x1 = location1[0].toFloat()
                    val y1 = location1[1] + view.height / 2.toFloat()
                    circleposX = x1 - 20.toFloat()
                    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, circleposX, y1, paintLine)
                    canvas.drawLine(circleposX, y1, circleposX, circleposY - circleIndicatorSize - 10, paintLine)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleIndicatorSize, paintCircle)
                    canvas.drawCircle(circleposX, circleposY, circleInnerIndicatorSize, paintCircleInner)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun dismiss() {
        ((context as Activity).window.decorView as ViewGroup).removeView(this)
        isShowing = false
        if (mGuideListener != null) {
            mGuideListener!!.onDismiss(target)
        }
        if (iOnTourButton != null) {
            iOnTourButton = null
            mMessageView.getButton().setOnClickListener { iOnTourButton }
            target!!.setOnClickListener { iOnTourButton }
        }
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val x = event.x
        val y = event.y
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            target!!.performClick()
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    private fun isViewContains(view: View, rx: Float, ry: Float): Boolean {
        val location = IntArray(2)
        view.getLocationOnScreen(location)
        val x = location[0]
        val y = location[1]
        val w = view.width
        val h = view.height
        return !(rx < x || rx > x + w || ry < y || ry > y + h)
    }

    private fun setMessageLocation(p: Point) {
        mMessageView.x = p.x.toFloat()
        mMessageView.y = p.y.toFloat()
        postInvalidate()
    }
    private fun resolveMessageViewLocation(): Point {

        var xMessageView = 0
        val locationTarget = IntArray(2)
        target!!.getLocationOnScreen(locationTarget)
        val x_pos = locationTarget[0] + target.width
        val y_pos = locationTarget[1] + target.height
        val dis_y = selfRect.bottom
        val dis_x = selfRect.right
        val dis_x1 = selfRect.left
        val targetRect_x = targetRect!!.top
        val targetRect_y = targetRect!!.right
        when {
            tourStep == 1 ->{
                xMessageView = (locationTarget[0] - target.width/2)
                yMessageView = (target.top - 50).toInt()
            }
            tourStep == 2  -> {
                xMessageView = locationTarget[0] - 20
                yMessageView = y_pos - target.height * 4 - mMessageView.getButton().height
            }
            tourStep == 3 -> {
                xMessageView = (locationTarget[0] - 40*density).toInt()
                yMessageView = y_pos - target.height * 4 - mMessageView.getButton().height
            }
            tourStep == 4 -> {
                xMessageView = dis_x + 40
                yMessageView = y_pos - target.height * 4 - mMessageView.getButton().height
            }
            tourStep == 5  -> {
                xMessageView = dis_x + 40
                yMessageView = y_pos - target.height * 4 - mMessageView.getButton().height
            }
            tourStep == 6 -> {
                xMessageView = (targetRect!!.left - 100 + target.width / 2).toInt()
                yMessageView = locationTarget[1] - target.height / 2 - 150
            }
            tourStep == 7 -> {
                xMessageView = (targetRect!!.left - mMessageView.width / 2 + target.width / 2).toInt()
                yMessageView = y_pos + target.height
            }
            tourStep == 8 -> {
                xMessageView = locationTarget[0] + 90
                yMessageView = y_pos - target.height * 3
            }
            tourStep == 9 -> {
                xMessageView = (targetRect!!.left - 60 + target.width / 2).toInt()
                yMessageView = y_pos - target.height * 4 - mMessageView.getButton().height
            }
            tourStep == 10 -> {
                xMessageView = (targetRect!!.left - mMessageView.width / 2 + target.width / 2).toInt()
                yMessageView = (target.top - 150)
            }
        }
        return Point(xMessageView, yMessageView)
    }

    fun show() {
        this.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
        this.isClickable = false
        ((context as Activity).window.decorView as ViewGroup).addView(this)
        val startAnimation = AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f)
        startAnimation.duration = APPEARING_ANIMATION_DURATION.toLong()
        startAnimation.fillAfter = true
        startAnimation(startAnimation)
        isShowing = true
    }

    fun setTitle(str: String?) {
        mMessageView.setTitle(str)
    }

    fun setButton(isNeeded: Boolean?) {
        if (!isNeeded!!) {
            mMessageView.getButton().visibility = INVISIBLE
            target!!.setOnClickListener { iOnTourButton!!.onTourButtonClicked(tourStep) }
        }
    }

    fun setButtonTitle(str: String?) {
        mMessageView.setButtonText(str)
    }

    fun setContentText(str: String?) {
        mMessageView.setContentText(str)
    }

    fun setContentSpan(span: Spannable?) {
        mMessageView.setContentSpan(span)
    }

    fun setTitleTypeFace(typeFace: Typeface?) {
        mMessageView.setTitleTypeFace(typeFace)
    }

    fun setContentTypeFace(typeFace: Typeface?) {
        mMessageView.setContentTypeFace(typeFace)
    }

    fun setTitleTextSize(size: Int) {
        mMessageView.setTitleTextSize(size)
    }

    fun setContentTextSize(size: Int) {
        mMessageView.setContentTextSize(size)
    }

    class Builder(private val context: Context) {
        private var targetView: View? = null
        private var title: String? = null
        private var contentText: String? = null
        private var buttonText: String? = null
        private var gravity: GRAVITY? = null
        private var targetType: TargetType? = null
        private var dismissType: DismissType? = null
        private var contentSpan: Spannable? = null
        private var titleTypeFace: Typeface? = null
        private var contentTypeFace: Typeface? = null
        private var guideListener: GuideListener? = null
        private var titleTextSize = 0
        private var contentTextSize = 0
        private var lineIndicatorHeight = 0f
        private var lineIndicatorWidthSize = 0f
        private var circleIndicatorSize = 0f
        private var circleInnerIndicatorSize = 0f
        private var strokeCircleWidth = 0f
        private var tourStep = 0
        private var isNeeded: Boolean? = true
        private var iOnTourButton: IOnTourButtonClicked? = null
        private var skipPresse: SkipPressed? = null

        fun setMessageView(tourStep: Int, iOnTourButton: IOnTourButtonClicked, view: View?, title: String?, contentText: String?, buttonText: String?, isNeeded: Boolean?, skipPresse: SkipPressed?): Builder {
            this.tourStep = tourStep
            this.targetView = view
            this.iOnTourButton = iOnTourButton
            this.skipPresse = skipPresse
            this.title = title
            this.contentText = contentText
            this.buttonText = buttonText
            this.isNeeded = isNeeded
            return this
        }

        /**
         * gravity GuideView
         *
         * @param gravity it should be one type of Gravity enum.
         */
        fun setGravity(gravity: GRAVITY?): Builder {
            this.gravity = gravity
            return this
        }

        /**
         * target TargetType
         *
         * @param targetType it should be one type of Gravity enum.
         */
        fun setTargetViewType(targetType: TargetType?): Builder {
            this.targetType = targetType
            return this
        }


        /**
         * setting spannable type
         *
         * @param span a instance of spannable
         */
        fun setContentSpan(span: Spannable?): Builder {
            contentSpan = span
            return this
        }

        /**
         * setting font type face
         *
         * @param typeFace a instance of type face (font family)
         */
        fun setContentTypeFace(typeFace: Typeface?): Builder {
            contentTypeFace = typeFace
            return this
        }

        /**
         * adding a listener on show case view
         *
         * @param guideListener a listener for events
         */
        fun setGuideListener(guideListener: GuideListener?): Builder {
            this.guideListener = guideListener
            return this
        }

        /**
         * setting font type face
         *
         * @param typeFace a instance of type face (font family)
         */
        fun setTitleTypeFace(typeFace: Typeface?): Builder {
            titleTypeFace = typeFace
            return this
        }

        /**
         * the defined text size overrides any defined size in the default or provided style
         *
         * @param size title text by sp unit
         * @return builder
         */
        fun setContentTextSize(size: Int): Builder {
            contentTextSize = size
            return this
        }

        /**
         * the defined text size overrides any defined size in the default or provided style
         *
         * @param size title text by sp unit
         * @return builder
         */
        fun setTitleTextSize(size: Int): Builder {
            titleTextSize = size
            return this
        }

        /**
         * this method defining the type of dismissing function
         *
         * @param dismissType should be one type of DismissType enum. for example: outside -> Dismissing with click on outside of MessageView
         */
        fun setDismissType(dismissType: DismissType?): Builder {
            this.dismissType = dismissType
            return this
        }

        /**
         * changing line height indicator
         *
         * @param height you can change height indicator (Converting to Dp)
         */
        fun setIndicatorHeight(height: Float): Builder {
            lineIndicatorHeight = height
            return this
        }

        /**
         * changing line width indicator
         *
         * @param width you can change width indicator
         */
        fun setIndicatorWidthSize(width: Float): Builder {
            lineIndicatorWidthSize = width
            return this
        }

        /**
         * changing circle size indicator
         *
         * @param size you can change circle size indicator
         */
        fun setCircleIndicatorSize(size: Float): Builder {
            circleIndicatorSize = size
            return this
        }

        /**
         * changing inner circle size indicator
         *
         * @param size you can change inner circle indicator size
         */
        fun setCircleInnerIndicatorSize(size: Float): Builder {
            circleInnerIndicatorSize = size
            return this
        }

        /**
         * changing stroke circle size indicator
         *
         * @param size you can change stroke circle indicator size
         */
        fun setCircleStrokeIndicatorSize(size: Float): Builder {
            strokeCircleWidth = size
            return this
        }

        fun build(): GuideView {
            val guideView = GuideView(context, targetView, targetType, tourStep, iOnTourButton)
            guideView.mGravity = if (gravity != null) gravity else GRAVITY.auto
            guideView.tourStep = tourStep
            guideView.mTargetType = if (targetType != null) targetType else TargetType.CIRCLE
            guideView.dismissType = if (dismissType != null) dismissType else DismissType.targetView
            guideView.isNeeded = isNeeded
            guideView.iOnTourButton = iOnTourButton
            guideView.skipPresse = skipPresse
            val density = context.resources.displayMetrics.density
            guideView.setTitle(title)
            guideView.setButtonTitle(buttonText)
            if (contentText != null) guideView.setContentText(contentText)
            if (titleTextSize != 0) guideView.setTitleTextSize(titleTextSize)
            if (contentTextSize != 0) guideView.setContentTextSize(contentTextSize)
            if (contentSpan != null) guideView.setContentSpan(contentSpan)
            if (!isNeeded!!) guideView.setButton(isNeeded)
            if (titleTypeFace != null) {
                guideView.setTitleTypeFace(titleTypeFace)
            }
            if (contentTypeFace != null) {
                guideView.setContentTypeFace(contentTypeFace)
            }
            /*if (guideListener != null) {
                guideView.mGuideListener = guideListener
            }*/
            if (lineIndicatorHeight != 0f) {
                guideView.indicatorHeight = lineIndicatorHeight * density
            }
            if (lineIndicatorWidthSize != 0f) {
                guideView.lineIndicatorWidthSize = lineIndicatorWidthSize * density
            }
            if (circleIndicatorSize != 0f) {
                guideView.circleIndicatorSize = circleIndicatorSize * density
            }
            if (circleInnerIndicatorSize != 0f) {
                guideView.circleInnerIndicatorSize = circleInnerIndicatorSize * density
            }
            if (strokeCircleWidth != 0f) {
                guideView.strokeCircleWidth = strokeCircleWidth * density
            }
            return guideView
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "GuideView"
        private const val INDICATOR_HEIGHT = 40
        private const val MESSAGE_VIEW_PADDING = 5
        private const val SIZE_ANIMATION_DURATION = 700
        private const val APPEARING_ANIMATION_DURATION = 400
        private const val CIRCLE_INDICATOR_SIZE = 6
        private const val LINE_INDICATOR_WIDTH_SIZE = 3
        private const val STROKE_CIRCLE_INDICATOR_SIZE = 3
        private const val RADIUS_SIZE_TARGET_RECT = 15
        private const val MARGIN_INDICATOR = 15
        private const val BACKGROUND_COLOR = -872415232
        private const val CIRCLE_INNER_INDICATOR_COLOR = -1720271361
        private const val CIRCLE_INDICATOR_COLOR = -2139701761
        private const val LINE_INDICATOR_COLOR = -9391377

    }

    init {
        setWillNotDraw(false)
        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)
        target = view
        density = context.resources.displayMetrics.density
        init()
        targetRect = if (view is Targetable) {
            (view as Targetable).boundingRect()
        } else {
            val locationTarget = IntArray(2)
            target!!.getLocationOnScreen(locationTarget)
            RectF(locationTarget[0].toFloat(),
                    locationTarget[1].toFloat(),
                    (locationTarget[0] + target.width).toFloat(),
                    (locationTarget[1] + target.height).toFloat())
        }
        mMessageView = GuideMessageView(getContext(), tourStep, iOnTourButton, isNeeded)
        mMessageView.setPadding(messageViewPadding, messageViewPadding, messageViewPadding, messageViewPadding)
        mMessageView.getSkipButton().setOnClickListener {
            val shareTour = SharedPref(context, SHARED_PREF_TOUR_GUIDE)
            if (tourStep in 1..6 || tourStep == 10 || tourStep == 9) {
                shareTour.setBoolean(DAY1, false)
            }
            if (tourStep == 7) {
                shareTour.setBoolean(DAY2, false)
            }
            if (tourStep == 11) {
                shareTour.setBoolean(DAY3, false)
            }
            dismiss()
            skipPresse!!.skipPressed(tourStep)
        }
        if (tourStep == 10 || tourStep == 7 || tourStep == 11)
            mMessageView.getSkipButton().visibility = GONE
        mMessageView.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        addView(mMessageView, LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
        setMessageLocation(resolveMessageViewLocation())
        val layoutListener: OnGlobalLayoutListener1 = object : OnGlobalLayoutListener1 {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                setMessageLocation(resolveMessageViewLocation())
                targetRect = if (target is Targetable) {
                    (target as Targetable).boundingRect()
                } else {
                    val locationTarget = IntArray(2)
                    target!!.getLocationOnScreen(locationTarget)
                    RectF(locationTarget[0].toFloat(),
                            locationTarget[1].toFloat(),
                            (locationTarget[0] + target.width).toFloat(),
                            (locationTarget[1] + target.height).toFloat())
                }
                selfRect[paddingLeft, paddingTop, width - paddingRight] = height - paddingBottom
                marginGuide = (if (isTop) marginGuide else -marginGuide)
                startYLineAndCircle = (if (isTop) targetRect!!.bottom else targetRect!!.top) + marginGuide
                stopY = yMessageView + indicatorHeight
                /*startAnimationSize()*/
                viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
            }
        }
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(layoutListener)
    }


}
```

***Also any help in optimizing the view***

Comment: Can you create a simple project and share it via Github. It would help a lot. Also for the performance issues, I think they are caused because you are creating objects in the `onDraw(..)` method, which is executed every 16 milliseconds. You are creating two arrays on every run and the chunked frames might be caused by the garbage collector which is doing heavy operations. Move the `val location = IntArray(2)` and `val location1 = IntArray(2)` from the `onDraw(...)` method to the `GuideView` and it should be OK. :)

Comment: OK Sure I will create a sample project

Comment: @StoyanMilev here adding the link to the sample project [link](https://github.com/DAKSHSEMWAL/GuideView/tree/master)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the sample project. I've looked into it and found out that you are showing your `GuideView` in `onBindViewHolder`, but view holders are being bound before shown on the screen. Which leads to wrong width, height, x and y position, etc.

My proposal is to create and show the `GuideView` when the holder of the `ViewPager` is shown and its positions won't vary.

Now the code. In `SummaryAdapter`

```
var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null

override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView
}

override fun onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
    this.recyclerView = null
    super.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView)
}

...

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SummaryHolder, position: Int) {
}

...

fun setCurrentPosition(position: Int) {
    val viewHolder = recyclerView?.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)
    if (viewHolder is SummaryHolder) {
        setGuideView(viewHolder.binding.rlHeartReport)
    }
}
```

In `MainActivity`:

```
    binding.viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {

        var isFirstPass = true

       override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            if (isFirstPass) {
                isFirstPass = false
                summaryAdapter.setCurrentPosition(position)
            }
        }

        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
            super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state)
            if (state == ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                summaryAdapter.setCurrentPosition(binding.viewPager.currentItem)
            }
        }
    })
```

And for the performance as I said in the comment -> make `location` and `location1` properties, move their creation away from the `onDraw` method.

Comment: Hi Stoyan, Thanks For taking out the time to look into my code and finding one of the fixes.I found another workaround for this by using   `graphView.post { guideView!!.show() }` I came across this accidentally when resuming the application the view drawn perfectly.